# assign variable to an individual table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to put images in a table. I have that working, if you click, you cycle through the available options. However, the counter is not cell related, it is a global counter. Is there a way to make a local variable, to keep track of where that individual cell is in the array?

I have tried making a local variable, only to a single cell, but it wasn't working.

Here is the related function in js:

```
var i = 1;
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var def = ["tex/white.png", "tex/grass.jpg", "tex/stone.jpg", "tex/water.jpg", "tex/wood.jpg", "tex/lava.jpg"];
table.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = (e || window.event).target;
    if (target.tagName in { TD: 1, TH: 1 }) {
        target.className = "img";
        console.log((e || window.event).target);
        target.setAttribute('style', 'background-image:' + "url(" + def[i] + ")");
        if (i < def.length) {
            i++
        }
        if (i == def.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Here is a working fiddle of what I have done so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/6L0armd4/

The desired result is that I start the array at single cells and it only counts for those cells. At the moment, it always gives the next texture, even when I select a different cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution : using ids to identify each cells, and an object to keep track of which background is currently used for each cells (using their id as key)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id='1'></td>
  <td id='2'></td>
  <td id='3'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id='4'></td>
  <td id='5'></td>
  <td id='6'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id='7'></td>
  <td id='8'></td>
  <td id='9'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var def = ["https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/5e4aedcf566fa5e4501ab584d357be01-full.jpg", "https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/3d39445ffda6687a6b0e80a69a35fdea-full.jpg"];
var currents = {}

getNextIndex = function(index) {
  return index === undefined || index >= def.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1
}

table.onclick = function(e) {
  var target = (e || window.event).target;    

  if (target.tagName in { TD: 1, TH: 1 }) {
    var new_bg_index = getNextIndex(currents[target.id])
    currents[target.id] = new_bg_index
    target.setAttribute('style', 'background-image:' + "url(" + def[new_bg_index] + ")");
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make listener event 
you may change the color codes to your image path on the below code  and avoid any local path image links issue try to  use online images direct ones .

```
var table = document.querySelector('#table')
var selectedCells = table.getElementsByClassName('selected')

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var td = e.target

if (td.tagName !== 'TD') {
return
}

if (selectedCells.length) {
selectedCells[0].className = ''    
}

td.className = 'selected'
})
table {
 cursor: text;
}
tr {
background-color:white;
}
td {
font-size: 14;
cursor: default;
}

td.selected {
background-color: red;

 // replace this with background image tag like this  
 background-image: url("paper.gif


<table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="2" id="table">
<tr>
<td>Cell one</td>
<td>Cell Tw</td>
<td>Cell three</td>
<td>Cell Four</td>
<td>Cell five</td>
<td>Cell sex</td>
<td>Cell five</td>
<td>cell seven</td>
<td>cell eight</td>
<td>cell nine</td>
<td>cell tens</td>
<td>cell eleven</td>
<td>cell twelve</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AKo</td>
<td>KK</td>
<td>KQs</td>
<td>KJs</td>
<td>KTs</td>
<td>K9s</td>
<td>K8S</td>
<td>K7s</td>
<td>K6s</td>
<td>K5s</td>
<td>K4s</td>
<td>K3s</td>
<td>K2s</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I need the images of the cell to remain there, not for a single cell to have the color at the same time.

Comment: I just added the image tag just remove the background  red color and replace it with your image , make sure the picture is placed within the root of your project , it will will :) I will adjust it more as I am gonna try it now and keep you posted